# 1117 voltage regularo ceramic caps

Tags: power-supply, ldo, stability, esr

I have made a mistake and I do not have the space on my PCB to add two serial resistors. Is it OK to use only one for two caps?

[image]

Simulation looks OK but it only the simulation

[image]

Comment: What is the point of the resistor (R2)?

Comment: Caps are ceramic - low ESR - need to add some resistance in series as in the TI application note.

Comment: You may want to consider a tantalum cap there of the same SMT size, as a temporary kludge to salvage the current batch of boards. But then you need to either re-spin the board, or find a better regulator than LM1117, or find a place the resistor. And I don 't think you need to increase the ESR on the 100nF cap.

Comment: I know that I can find another regulator or capacitors. But my question is about this particular config. Can it be like this or if not why?